# Checkbox in CustomListField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I am creating a CustomList. In each row I am having a image, some text fields and a checkbox. But i am not able to check and uncheck the checkbox.
I have gone through this link but cant solve my problem.

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_ListField_with_check_boxes.html?nodeid=1165752&vernum=0

this will add a menu item in the menu to change the checkbox status. 
I want the normal checkbox behaviour.
Please help

this is my code

```
class CustomList extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback
{

public Vector rows;
private Bitmap p1;
int z = this.getRowHeight();    
LabelField task,task2,task3;
CheckboxField checkbox[]= new CheckboxField[40];
int rowcount;
public CustomList(int rowcount,String text1,double text2,String type,Bitmap p)
{
    super(0, ListField.MULTI_SELECT);
    this.rowcount= rowcount;
    setRowHeight(z*3);
    setEmptyString("Hooray, no tasks here!", DrawStyle.HCENTER);
    setCallback(this);        
    p1 = p;     
    rows = new Vector();

    for (int x = 0; x < rowcount; x++) 
    {
        checkbox[x]=new CheckboxField("",false,Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT|Field.EDITABLE|Field.FIELD_VCENTER|Field.FOCUSABLE);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < rowcount; x++) 
    {
        TableRowManager row = new TableRowManager();            
        row.add(checkbox[x]);
        row.add(new BitmapField(p1));
        task= new LabelField("abc");
        row.add(task);
        task2=new LabelField("abc2");
        row.add(task2);
        task3= new LabelField("abc3");
        row.add(task3);
        rows.addElement(row);
    }
    setSize(rows.size());
}
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g, int index, int y,int width) 
{
    CustomList list = (CustomList) listField;
    TableRowManager rowManager = (TableRowManager) list.rows.elementAt(index);
    rowManager.drawRow(g, 0, y, width, list.getRowHeight());
}

private class TableRowManager extends Manager 
{
    public TableRowManager() 
    {
    super(0);
    }

// Causes the fields within this row manager to be layed out then
// painted.
    public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) 
    {
        layout(width, height);
        setPosition(x, y);
        g.pushRegion(getExtent());
        subpaint(g);
        g.setColor(0x00CACACA);
        g.popContext();
    }
    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) 
    {
        // set the size and position of each field.
    }
    public int getPreferredWidth() 
    {
        return UIConstants.SCREEN_WIDTH;
    }
    public int getPreferredHeight() 
    {
        return getRowHeight();
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to implement listfield with checkboxes and i have seen its code in the knowledge base.

But i want that when i click on the checkbox it should be checked or unchecked onlyand when i click on the rest part of the row, i.e. anywhere except the checkbox then nothing should occur without checking the checkbox

How can i do that ?? Or i should do something else to do it.. Please suggest..

Comment: what do you want? You want to check that is checkbox is selected or nor? or anything;

Comment: Can't help you without code. I don't have a crystal ball.... yet jejeje

Comment: @alishaik786 hey hi.. I have mentioned that I want to check the checkbox present in the ListField.

Comment: @JuanmaBaiutti- I have edited my question. and added the whole code.. please help

Comment: If you dont want to use entire row state change event, then just override that event and manage state of your list, on that event.

Comment: @jitendrasharma Can U help me with some code plz..

Comment: You should do something else. One of the problems is that none of your TableRowManagers are ever added to a UI manager. Neither they, nor their children will ever see UI events. The ListField is not intended to manage other UI element objects. It is designed to be able to handle very large data sets without creating a bunch of UI object for each item. If you really want to use UI objects like this, replace ListField with a class that extends Manager, perhaps GridFieldManager or VerticalFieldManager.

Comment: @Richard I am adding the tableRowManager to the vector rows.Can you help me in adding the TableRowManager to the UI Manager.

Comment: hi swathi,iam also getting same pblm.did u finded any solution for this pblm.

Comment: ya instead of the list item if u can make it with the help of horizontalFieldManager

Comment: can u paste your solved code here

Comment: swathi.can u please  put your solved code here.iam trying.but iam not able to check and uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: i posted a question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793684/custom-listfield-with-checkboxes-in-blackberry can u see my code and can you give any solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this where you are overriding your sublayOut method() in table row manager class

```
protected void sublayout(int width, int height) 
{
    Field field = getField(0);            
                layoutChild(field, Display.getWidth(),   Display.getHeight());             
                setPositionChild(field, 10, 20);

Field field = getField(0);            
                layoutChild(field, Display.getWidth(),    Display.getHeight());            
                setPositionChild(field, 10, 20);

                //Set field           
                field = getField(1);
                layoutChild(field, 120, fontHeight - 1 );             
                setPositionChild(field, 70, 05);

                // set the list field             
                field = getField(2);              
                layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight +10);              
                setPositionChild(field, 70, 25);

                // set the field               
                field = getField(3);              
                layoutChild(field, (Display.getWidth()/6)-12, fontHeight + 10);       
                setPositionChild(field, 70, 45);    
                setExtent(preferredWidth, getPreferredHeight());
}
```

change the padding as your require ments.

And you can also check this link [create a listField with check box](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-ListField-with-check-boxes/ta-p/443009). Thanks

Comment: that i have done. I am able to add the checkbox.. but not able to take the action on click of it

Comment: that you have to do on click method override navigationClick(), or touchEvent(), or fieldChanged() to get this functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
  boolean checked = false;
  Vector box1 = new Vector();  
  for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++){
    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)vector.elementAt(i);
    String name=co_vec.getSender_name();
    CheckboxField box = new CheckboxField(" "+name , checked, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
               graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
              super.paint(graphics);
            }
         };
         box1.addElement(box);
         box.setMargin(8, 0, 0, 5);
         add(box);

      }
```

then add a button. On the click listener of the button,

```
         for(int d=0; d<box1.size(); d++){
            CheckboxField box=(CheckboxField)box1.elementAt(d);
                  if(box.getChecked()==true){
                    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)vector.elementAt(d);
                    String name_ = co_vec.getSender_name();
                    Dialog.alert(name_);// here you can implement your code
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Thanx Rez.. but i dont have a button there.. my app demands on click of the checkbox.

Comment: Try to check wether the check box is checked or not(can be done within a thread). If check box is checked, then do what you want to do.

Comment: this is the problem.. no events are happening on checkbox.

Comment: in a thread , do this-    for(int d=0; d<box1.size(); d++){
            CheckboxField box=(CheckboxField)box1.elementAt(d);
                  if(box.getChecked()==true){
                    // here you can implement your code
                  }
                }