# Custom ListField With Checkboxes in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I tried to implement the custom `ListField` with checkboxes in blackberry. I'm able to display the list correctly. My requirement is that I need to select some multiple items using the checkbox in blackberry, but I'm not able to change the check and uncheck the checkbox. I tried in `navigationClick`, `CheckBox.setChangeListener`, `HorizontalFieldManager.setChangeListener` methods, but I didn't get any solutions. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

My code is:

```
public class InboxWithCheckboxes extends MainScreen{
    private InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield;
    public MenuItem _DeleteMessage;
    private String[]templongDBTimeStamp;
    private Database db;
    private static final int[] GRADIENT_COLORS     =
    {
        Color.PALEVIOLETRED, Color.ANTIQUEWHITE, Color.DARKTURQUOISE, Color.DEEPSKYBLUE
    };
    protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance)
    {
        menu.add(_DeleteMessage);

        //Create the default menu.
        super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
    }
    public InboxWithCheckboxes(){
        inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield = new InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield();
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground( 
                GRADIENT_COLORS[0], GRADIENT_COLORS[1], 
                GRADIENT_COLORS[2], GRADIENT_COLORS[3]);
        this.getMainManager().setBackground(
                bg);

        add(inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield);     
        add(new SeparatorField()); 
        db = new Database();

        _DeleteMessage = new MenuItem("DeleteMessage", 200, 10){
            public void run(){
                int index[] = inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.getSelection();
                System.out.println("the list size is:"+inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.getSize());
                for(int i=0;i<inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.getSize();i++){
                int index1 = inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(" selected index is:"+index1);

                inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.delete(index1);
                inboxWithCheckboxeslistfield.eraseAt(index1);

                }
                invalidate();   

            }
        };
    }
}


class InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback  {
    public Vector rows;
    private TableRowManager row ;
    public TableRowManager rowManager;
    private LabelField UserName,Message,Timestamp;
    private HorizontalFieldManager hfmcheck;

    private CheckboxField checkbox;

    private Database db;
    private Vector inboxdatavector;
    private String[] msg,key,userinfo,timearray;
    private long[] timeStamp;
    /* Border For EditFields */
    Border bdr = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(new XYEdges(4, 4, 4, 4),
            Border.STYLE_SOLID);


    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        super(0, ListField.MULTI_SELECT);
        setRowHeight(120);
        setCallback(this);
        rows = new Vector();
        db = new Database();
        inboxdatavector = db.fetchDataInbox();
        int count = db.getcountInbox();
        msg = new String[count];
        key =  new String[count];
        userinfo =  new String[count];
        timearray = new String[count];
        timeStamp = new long[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            row = new TableRowManager() { 
                public void paint(Graphics g) { 
                    g.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); 
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); 
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
                    g.clear(); 
                    super.paint(g); 
                } 
            }; 
            try{
                byte[] a = (byte[]) inboxdatavector.elementAt(i);
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(a);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
                msg[i]= dis.readUTF();
                key[i] = dis.readUTF();
                userinfo[i] = dis.readUTF();
                timeStamp[i] = dis.readLong();
                timearray[i] = convertMillisecondsToDate(timeStamp[i]);
                System.out.println("msg is "+msg[i]);
                System.out.println("key is "+key[i]);
                System.out.println("userinfo is "+userinfo[i]);
                System.out.println("timeStamp is "+timeStamp[i]);

                bais.close();
                dis.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            UserName = new LabelField("" + String.valueOf(i),
                    DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                    | DrawStyle.LEFT);
            UserName.setText(userinfo[i]);
            row.add(UserName);
            hfmcheck = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
            row.add(hfmcheck);
            checkbox = new CheckboxField("",false,Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
                public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    super.paint(graphics);
                }
            };
            hfmcheck.add(checkbox);
            hfmcheck.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("entered into hfmfield");
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                }
            });
            Message = new LabelField("" + String.valueOf(i),
                    DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                    | DrawStyle.RIGHT);
            Message.setText(msg[i]);
            row.add(Message);


            Timestamp = new LabelField("" + String.valueOf(i),
                    DrawStyle.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH
                    | DrawStyle.RIGHT);
            Timestamp.setText(timearray[i]);
            row.add(Timestamp);

            rows.addElement(row);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userinfo.length; i++) {
            timearray[i] = convertMillisecondsToDate(timeStamp[i]);
            System.out.println("the time is:"+timearray[i]);

        }
        /*checkbox.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("enter into checked changed.");
                checkbox.setChecked(true);

            }
        });*/
        setSize(rows.size());


    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
            int y, int width) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield list = (InboxWithCheckboxeslistfield) listField;
        rowManager = (TableRowManager) list.rows.elementAt(index);
        ((TableRowManager) rowManager).drawRow(graphics, 0, y, width, list.getRowHeight());



    }
    public void erase() {  
        rows.removeAllElements();  
    }

    public void eraseAt(int index) {  
        rows.removeElementAt(index);

    }
    private class TableRowManager extends Manager {

        protected TableRowManager(){
            super(0);
        }

        public void drawRow(Graphics graphics, int i, int y, int width,
                int rowHeight) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Arrange the cell fields within this row manager.
            layout(width, rowHeight);

            // Place this row manager within its enclosing list.
            setPosition(i, y);

            // Apply a translating/clipping transformation to the graphics
            // context so that this row paints in the right area.
            graphics.pushRegion(getExtent());

            // Paint this manager's controlled fields.
            subpaint(graphics);
            graphics.setColor(0x00CACACA);
            graphics.drawLine(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), 0);

            // Restore the graphics context.
            graphics.popContext();

        }


        protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // set the size and position of each field.
            int fontHeight = Font.getDefault().getHeight();
            int preferredWidth = getPreferredWidth();

            Field field = getField(0);

            layoutChild(field, preferredWidth, 50); 
            setPositionChild(field, 10, 5);

            field = getField(1);
            layoutChild(field, preferredWidth, 150); 
            setPositionChild(field, 10,40);


            // set the list name label field
            field = getField(2);
            layoutChild(field, 300, fontHeight + 1); 
            //setPositionChild(field, 1, 2); 
            setPositionChild(field, 80, fontHeight );

            // set the due time name label field
            field = getField(3);
            layoutChild(field, 150, fontHeight + 1);
            setPositionChild(field, 500, fontHeight );



            setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());

        }
        // The preferred width of a row is defined by the list renderer.  
        public int getPreferredWidth()  
        {       

            return Display.getWidth();        
        } 
        // The preferred height of a row is the "row height" as defined in the  
        // enclosing list.      
        public int getPreferredHeight()     
        { 
            return getRowHeight();       
        } 


    }
    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) { 
        return null; 
    } 

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) { 
        return 0; 
    } 


    public String convertMillisecondsToDate(long timeStamp) {

        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date information.

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(timeStamp);
        System.out.println("the date is:"+formatter.formatLocal(date.getTime()));
        return formatter.formatLocal(date.getTime());
    }
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
        /*_DeleteMessage = new MenuItem("DeleteMessage", 200, 10){
            public void run(){
                System.out.println("entered into delete item");
                int index = getSelectedIndex();
                System.out.println(" selected index is:"+index);
                for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++){
                    rows.removeElementAt(index);
                    invalidate();
                }
            }

        };*/
        return true;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
CheckboxField box;
Vector box1 = new Vector();
boolean checked = false;

for(int i=0;i<fbFrndsVector.size();i++){
    //your object class and vector.     
    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)fbFrndsVector.elementAt(i);

    String name=co_vec.getSender_name();
    String id=co_vec.getSender_id();

    box = new CheckboxField(" "+name , checked, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
               graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
              super.paint(graphics);
            }
         };

         box1.addElement(box);
         box.setMargin(8, 0, 0, 5);
         vfm.add(box);


}

add(vfm);
```

//on your button click, write the below code-

```
    Vector selected_frnd=new Vector();
    private Vector _selected_frnds;


        for(int d=0; d<box1.size(); d++){
                CheckboxField box=(CheckboxField)box1.elementAt(d);
                  if(box.getChecked()==true){
                    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)fbFrndsVector.elementAt(d);

                    String name_ = co_vec.getSender_name();
                    String id_ = co_vec.getSender_id();
                    FriendsRequestObject sfrnds = new FriendsRequestObject(id_, name_);
                    selected_frnd.addElement(sfrnds);


                  }
                }
```

the vector selected_frnd will  contains all the selected items.

Comment: thanks i have able to generated list  using the above code but iam not able to get the selected items when i clicked on a button. how to achieve this